# Using transport_type "beacon" does not hide parameters in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

Maybe I'm missing something here, but in Google Analytics V3 (analytics.js or gtag.js) setting the `transport` or `transport_type` to `beacon` would make the request to `google-analytics.com/x/collect` be sent using POST, i.e. no GET-parameters would be shown in the request URL.

When using GA4 (and a G- measurement ID) setting this parameter does nothing. This is what my tracking code looks like:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXX', {"transport_type":"beacon"});
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I simply misinterpreting how the `beacon` works in GA4? If the latter, is there any way to make GA4 function in a similar manner? What I'd like to achieve is send requests, that look like:

`https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect`

As opposed to:

`https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?param=1&param_2=2&etc=etc`

Hopefully someone'll be able to help me out, as the documentation is very limited ATM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox in Network section of developer tools you can see the initiator of hit, and it say the way how hit was sent. If you see something like `js.56 (beacon)` you can be sure that hit was sent via `navigator.sendBeacon()` method of Beacon API

[image]

Setting parameter `transport_type` to `beacon` indeed do nothing, because ga4 hits are sent using this method by default.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also explain why in V3 the parameters were hidden when using a beacon, and in V3 they're not?

Comment: I think there no other answer than "because they could do it". Only possible request method in `navigator.sendBeacon()` is post, but you can still make valid post request with empty (or minimal) body and parse all needed informations in url. Maybe Universal Analytics engineers wants to make this more obvious, that changing transport type change also request method but GA4 engineers doesn't want to confuse old analytics user and now parameters aren't shown in the url event if all requests are post now? Just wild guess.